# AWK - how to find unique vaulues and print first and last occurance

Tags: awk, grep

I have a large text file which has multiple lines of data relating to one item, an item can have upto 15 different lines but all linked by a field called "itemId" i.e. itemId=<12560317> each line has a timestamp at the beginning i.e. 170209 035711 0792.

```
170209 035711 0638 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REPLY>, *********************, itemId=<12560284>, globalId=<12560284>, cmcIndex=<728>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, ccReason=<SCANNER_DATA_ADDED>, 
170209 035711 0638 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM>, *************************, itemId=<12560284>, globalId=<12560284>, cmcIndex=<728>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, PendingchuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, Pendingstrategy=<notSpecified>, CscdestinationId=<-1: UnDef>, CmcdestinationId=<4099: All Scanners>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4000: SCAN01>, itemRevisionNumber=<7> ##[
170209 035711 0715 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<SCANNER_RESULT>, ************************, itemId=<12560311>, globalId=<12560311>, cmcIndex=<755>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, barcodeCount=<4>
170209 035711 0715 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REQUEST>, *******************, itemId=<12560311>, globalId=<12560311>, cmcIndex=<755>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, barcodes=<[ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<JJD014600001372909310>,
170209 035711 0717 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DISCHARGE_ATTEMPTED>, *******************, itemId=<12560209>, globalId=<12560209>, cmcIndex=<653>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectHeadingForChute>, CscdestinationId=<19: CHU208>, chuteGroup=<[17, 19, 21]: [CHU207, CHU208, CHU209]>, CmcdestinationId=<19: CHU208>, position=<sorter#0: MS01>, itemRevisionNumber=<16> ##[
170209 035711 0719 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REPLY>, *********************, itemId=<12560311>, globalId=<12560311>, cmcIndex=<755>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, ccReason=<SCANNER_DATA_ADDED>, PendingccResult=<OK>, Pendingstrategy=<notSpecified>,
170209 035711 0719 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM>, *************************, itemId=<12560311>, globalId=<12560311>, cmcIndex=<755>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, PendingchuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, Pendingstrategy=<notSpecified>, CscdestinationId=<-1: UnDef>, CmcdestinationId=<-1: UnDef>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4001: IU04-SCAN02>, itemRevisionNumber=<4> ##[
170209 035711 0792 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<ITEM_AT_INDUCTION>, *********************, itemId=<12560317>, globalId=<12560317>, cmcIndex=<761>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectIdle>, inductionId=<3: IU04>, position=<sorter#0.induction#3: IU04>, itemRevisionNumber=<0> ##[
170209 035711 0792 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<SET_ITEM_ID>, ***************************, itemId=<12560317>, globalId=<12560317>, cmcIndex=<761>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: ProjectIdle>, itemRevisionNumber=<0> ##[
170209 035711 0794 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM_REPLY>, *******************, itemId=<12560284>, globalId=<12560284>, cmcIndex=<728>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, CscdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, chuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, CmcdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4000: SCAN01>, chuteListStartPoint=<-1>, itemRevisionNumber=<9> ##[
170209 035711 0795 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<RECONVERT>, *****************************, itemId=<12560284>, globalId=<12560284>, cmcIndex=<728>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, CscdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, chuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, CmcdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, position=<sorter#0.scanner#4000: SCAN01>, chuteListStartPoint=<-1>, itemRevisionNumber=<10> ##[
170209 035711 0795 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<DESTINATION_REQUEST>, *******************, itemId=<12560284>, globalId=<12560284>, cmcIndex=<728>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, barcodes=<[ProxyWrapperBarcode(barcode=<JJD014600004019604475>, type=<C0>, result=<OK>, ccType=<>), 
170209 035711 0797 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<REDIRECT_ITEM_REPLY>, *******************, itemId=<12560311>, globalId=<12560311>, cmcIndex=<755>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForDestination>, CscdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, chuteGroup=<[3000]: Parked0>, CmcdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>,
170209 035711 0798 DE(N) ItemHandler.ItemLog event=<ITEM_INDUCTED>, *************************, itemId=<12560311>, globalId=<12560311>, cmcIndex=<755>, sorter=<0: MS01>, state=<CSC: WaitForData>, inductionId=<3: IU04>, inductionMode=<SCANNER>, inductStatus=<NORMAL_ITEM>, carrierId=<469>, carrierCount=<1>, CmcdestinationId=<3000: Parked0>, position=<sorter#0: MS01>, itemRevisionNumber=<7> ##[
```

Objective :

What I want to do is using gawk in Windows is find the first occurance of ITEMID and grab the date and time and the last time occurance it was seen and grab the data and time. and put these onto one line such as

```
ITEMID  170209 035711   170209 035932
```

Is there a way I can do this using GREP or AWK or a combination

Thanks

Comment: where are *data and time* in your input?

Comment: Roman the date format is YYMMDD HHMMSS then hundreds of seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oneliner is:

```
gawk '{ a = gensub(/([0-9]{6} [0-9]{6} [0-9]{4}).*itemId=<([0-9]+)>.*/, "\\2 \\1", "g", $0); b = split(a, c, " "); if (c[1] in result) result[c[1]] = gensub(/(.+),(.+)/, "\\1," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4], "g", result[c[1]]); else result[c[1]] = c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4] "," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4]} END { for (i in result) print i ": " result[i]}' test.txt
```

Let me evaluate:

- var a contains the itemId and date from a line
- we split a using spaces, a[1] contains itemId, a[2],a[3],a[4] parts of the date
- if the itemId doesn't yet exist in array "result", we put the date twice(!) in the array "result" with index itemId,
- if the itemId already exists, we replace the second date by the newly found date.

This leaves us with assoc array with itemId as key and as value the first and the last date, separated by a comma.

```
gawk '{ 
  a = gensub(/([0-9]{6} [0-9]{6} [0-9]{4}).*itemId=<([0-9]+)>.*/, "\\2 \\1", "g", $0);
  b = split(a, c, " "); 
  if (c[1] in result) 
     result[c[1]] = gensub(/(.+),(.+)/, "\\1" "," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4], "g", result[c[1]]);
  else result[c[1]] = c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4] "," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4]
} END { for (i in result) print i ": " result[i]}' test.txt
```

And the result is:

```
12560311: 170209 035711 0715,170209 035711 0798
12560209: 170209 035711 0717,170209 035711 0717
12560284: 170209 035711 0638,170209 035711 0795
12560317: 170209 035711 0792,170209 035711 0792
```

EDIT:
Running this on windows didn't work correctly. Simplified the answer to:

```
awk "
!first[$8] {first[$8] = $1 FS $2 FS $3} 
{last[$8] = $1 FS $2 FS $3 } 
END {
for (id in first) {
   print gensub(/itemId=<([^>]+)>,/, \"\\1\", \"g\", id) FS first[id] FS last[id]}
}" Item.log
```

Thx to @glennjackman for inspiration. ;-) Note the escaping of quotes for running this on windows.

Comment: mlam's -   WOW this looks epic, I will have a go and see if it works, appreciate you taking the time to have a look at this

Comment: mlam - stupid question, how do I input the source file into your gawk statement ?

Comment: I've put your example input in a file called 'test.txt'. So you can replace that name in my code example by your own filename.

Comment: gawk "{ a = gensub(/([0-9]{6} [0-9]{6} [0-9]{4}).*itemId=<([0-9]+)>.*/, "\\2 \\1", "g", $0); b = split(a, c, " "); if (c[1] in result) result[c[1]] = gensub(/(.+),(.+)/, "\\1," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4], "g", result[c[1]]); else result[c[1]] = c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4] "," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4]} END { for (i in result) print i ": " result[i]}" Item.log

Comment: You should use single quotes around the code. So "'" and not """.

Comment: Hi Mal, sorry for the late reply, I always have to use " quote when I'm writing grep and gawk statemetns on my PC ?  I'm running the statement in the .bat file will this affect it ?

Comment: C:\00 - Beumer\DailyStats\System Logs>gawk '{a = gensub(/([0-9]{6} [0-9]{6} [0-9]{4}).*itemId=, "\\2 \\1", "g", $0); b = split(a, c, " "); if (c[1] in result) result[c[1]] = gensub(/(.+),(.+)/, "\\1," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4], "g", result[c[1]]); else result[c[1]] = c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4] "," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4]} END { for (i in result) print i ": " result[i]}' Item.log 0<([0-9]+) 1>.*/
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: mlam when I run it I get the above response and it seems to add 0<([0-9]+) 1>.*/  to the end of the line and i get the file error ?

Comment: @Fabby You should be using: gawk '{a = gensub(/([0-9]{6} [0-9]{6} [0-9]{4}).*itemId=, "\\2 \\1", "g", $0); b = split(a, c, " "); if (c[1] in result) result[c[1]] = gensub(/(.+),(.+)/, "\\1," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4], "g", result[c[1]]); else result[c[1]] = c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4] "," c[2] " " c[3] " " c[4]} END { for (i in result) print i ": " result[i]}' Item.log

Comment: HI Mlam thanks for picking this up again I get the foillowing when I run the above log
gawk: cmd. line:1: '{a
gawk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: This is why I have had to use " in the past to get scripts to run on my laptop using gawk

Comment: Ah, windows. Use double quotes and escape all quotation marks withing the braces: gawk "{ a = gensub(/([0-9]{6} [0-9]{6} [0-9]{4}).*itemId=<([0-9]+)>.*/, \"\\2 \\1\", \"g\", $0); b = split(a, c, \" \"); if (c[1] in result) result[c[1]] = gensub(/(.+),(.+)/, \"\\1,\" c[2] \" \" c[3] \" \" c[4], \"g\", result[c[1]]); else result[c[1]] = c[2] \" \" c[3] \" \" c[4] \",\" c[2] \" \" c[3] \" \" c[4]} END { for (i in result) print i \": \" result[i]}" Item.log

Comment: Mlam -  PERFECT absolutely Perfect thank you so so much for your help, it has made such a difference to what I plan and can do

Comment: Well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Mlam, when I now run it I only get one line out of a file of 566k was expecting more ?

Comment: Show me first 20 lines of your input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152967/discussion-between-fabby-and-mlambrichs).

Answer (score 2):

I would write:

```
awk '
    !first[$8] {first[$8] = $0} 
    {last[$8] = $0} 
    END {for (id in first) {print first[id]; print last[id]}}
' file
```

Do you need the output sorted by date or by id or ...? Do you want to just lookup a single id at a time?

Comment: Hi Glenn, appreciate your reply, don't need it sorted but trying to ultimately calculate the Duration i.e. last occurance - first occurance

Comment: GNU awk has some builtin time functions that you can use: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions